# JQuery AJAX Request/Response

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Is there a JQuery built-in function or an easy way to get the time an AJAX request has taken to receive a server response? it might be a bit tricky that all my AJAX requests are asynchronous, for example there could be a second request sent by the client under way before receiving a first request response therefore a unique identification for each request is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery.ajaxStart() and jQuery.ajaxComplete() functions to record the time to get response from server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebug on firefox or the Inspector in Chrome

Comment: The context of my questions is clearly related to doing this programmatically, I asked about a JQuery function.